# Same UI for Electron-users and Browser-users

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, electron

Is it possible to use same index.html both from Electron process and browser like Chrome?

I made an app that uses it's own Hapi server to serve http requests to db and it works fine.
Now I'm trying to serve `index.html` from inside of Electron's asar but got an error 
"module is not defined" opening Hapi's route in Chrome.

As I guess `renderer.js` is compiled using **es2016** instead of **es2015**. I've tryied using webpack plugins but none of them even let me recompile an app throwing different mistakes.

Used [that](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) template.

Is there some good way to archive identical UI for Electron-users and Browser-users?

EDIT: found similar issue https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/195

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can but some other code is failing. Is `module is not defined` the whole error? If not please add to post

Comment: @MikeWood nope, it's single error. But I've found similar issue on template's developer docs. Please refer to edited description.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your requiring something like ipc-renderer but that isn't supported in the browser so you need to check if your running in the browser or not using something like this:

```
if (window && window.process && window.process.type) {
    var ipc = require('ipc-renderer');
}
```

So if it's in the browser it won't require it.

[How to detect if running in electron.](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288)